# Cloudinary authorization with direct upload

Tags: php, html, cloudinary

I created a working clientside upload script for cloudinary. The important part of the upload:

```
<?php
    $cloudName = "...";
    $apiKey = "...";
    $time = time();
    $apiSecret = "...";
    $fileName = "...";
?>              
<form action="https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<?php echo $cloudName;?>/image/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="signature" value="<?php echo sha1('public_id='.$fileName.'&timestamp='.$time.$apiSecret);?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="api_key" value="<?php echo $apiKey; ?>"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="timestamp" value="<?php echo $time; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="public_id" value="<?php echo $fileName; ?>" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Now I want to add a transformation to the upload, so the uploads are transformed before they are stored (to save storage space).

I tried adding the following code (where resize is a transformation I created in my cloudinary account).

```
<input type="hidden" name="transformation" value="resize" />
```

But a request with a transformation field results in a **401 unauthorized** error. I suppose I have to do something with the signature, but what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the cl_form_tag from the [cloudinary PHP client library](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_php) to build the form with all the input tags. However, you might want to use the jQuery direct upload which gives you better control and is more customizable UI-wise. See [here](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/php_image_upload#direct_uploading_from_the_browser). If you can't use the PHP client library for some reason there are two issues in the code:

1. A named transformation can be used by prefixing it by t_. So the value of the transformation field should be t_resize.
2. The transformation parameter needs to be added to the signature. Note that the parameter names need to be in alphabetical order when signed.

Comment: Thanks! I added t_ to the transformation and added it to the signature in alphabetical order and it is working now!